# Retrofit 2 Callback onResponse on background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit2

This has probably been asked before but didn't seem to have a viable answer. We are using Retrofit 2.1.0 async callback which carries out the request on the background thread. However, when the response is received `onResponse` it is sent back on the application's UI thread regardless of me placing the callback within a new thread forcing it to not utilize the UI.

As we don't want to block the main UI thread for any reason, is it possible for the response to be returned in the background?

If the above is not possible, is it recommended that a separate thread is kicked off from the response in order to avoid UI thread blocking?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can specify a specific executor for the callbacks to run on when building your `Retrofit` instance.  Here is an example that uses a `SingleThreadExecutor` for callbacks.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(/* your url */)
        .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        // other builder options...
        .build();
```

Comment: If you will use it for making requests from background thread every 10-15 secounds it will produce many threads and app wil crash through couple of minutes.

Comment: @user7856586 I think the thread from `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` has a queue to do work so it doesn't constantly create new threads.

Comment: This method will not work as it will raise an IllegalStateException if you are using call.enqueue method, Method call should happen from the main thread.